# Python Pandas read excel while excel file is opened

Tags: python, excel, pandas

how I read the excel file with python pandas:

```
excelData = pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheet_name=["Qualifying Results", "Race Results", "Ligadaten"])
```

but I get the following error when executing the script while the excel file is opened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auswahl.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "classification.py", line 55, in exec
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1376, in __init__
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1250, in inspect_excel_format
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 795, in get_handle
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '..\\LigaV4.4.xlsm'
[21960] Failed to execute script 'auswahl' due to unhandled exception!
```

when I execute the script while the excel file is closed everything workes fine.

Is there a way to execute the python script when the excel file is opened and not crash?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743905/pd-read-excel-throws-permissionerror-if-file-is-open-in-excel#:~:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%27t%20even,to%20see%20if%20it%20helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AFAIK this is not possible.
If you want to acces an opened excel file you can look into [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/), but this cannot directly connect to pandas using `pd.read_excel`.
If you want the crash to stop, you can catch the error ofcourse, but the part where it reads the Excel will not function.