# Reading an open spreadsheet with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas used to read the latest saved version of an open spreadsheet - the file was open in Excel, but pandas would still read and load it.  This was convenient.  I could tweak the spreadsheet, save, and import without closing.

Now when I try to read an open spreadsheet, I get:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I'm not trying to write to an open file, just read it.

I did recently change computers and OS from Windows 11 to 10.  I updated conda.

Any way I can get around the error and not need to close the spreadsheet to read?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743905/pd-read-excel-throws-permissionerror-if-file-is-open-in-excel for some suggestions and workarounds